# Djnago, is it possible to create multiple status choice with a model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-views

This is my actually `models.py`, that give me the possibility to create the status for a multiple choice:

```
class Status(models.Model):
      slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
      category = models.TextField()


class Example(models.Model):
      category= models.ForeignKey(Status)
```

I want to have the possibility to add a sub category. In other words, if I create a new category "Product" in my `status model`, I want to have the possibility to create the sub category choice, dipendet from the category, and selectable in my Example model in a new field called sub_category.

Ad example: with Status.models the client can create the category of a product, for istance "car" and the related sub category "whell", "steering wheel" and so on. After, when fill Example.models and choose in category "Car", the client can select only the sub_category stored before ("whell", "steering wheel"). I hope that now my explanation is better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a foreign key to the same model multiple times, but you need to include the `related_name` argument.

#### The all Python way

```py
# models.py

class Status(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    category = models.TextField()
    # This allows us to have hierarchy of categories.
    parent =  models.ForeignKey(
        "self", 
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        related_name="children", 
        related_query_name="child",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
    )


class Example(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Status, 
        related_name="example_categories",
        limit_choices_to={'parent': None},
    )
    # This field is hidden on new objects.
    sub_category = models.ForeignKey(
        Status,
        related_name="example_sub_categories",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
```

```
# forms.py

class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # When we instantiate the form, we check if the object 'instance' exists.
        # If it does not, we hide the `sub_category` field.
        # Otherwise we restrict the queryset to children of the `category` field.

        # NOTE: this will need to be properly cleaned. It does not prevent editing
        # the parent `category` after the `sub_category` has already been saved.
        instance = kwargs.get('instance')
        if not instance:
            self.fields.get('sub_category').widget = forms.HiddenInput()
        else:
            sub_cateogries = Status.objects.filter(parent=instance.category).all()
            self.fields.get('sub_category').queryset = sub_cateogries
```

```py
# admin.py

@admin.register(Example)
class ExampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ExampleForm
```

This method suffers from needing to save the object once, and then being able to edit the subcategories. This is not ideal as it adds a second step to the object management cycle.

#### The Better Way

*The better way of handling this is more involved and requires some JS so I won't provide code here. However, I will explain what it is and how it can be done.*

You can use Select2 to perform an AJAX request to a custom admin view that returns a list of the subcategories as a JSON array.

Adding a custom admin view is easy enough just make sure to check `user.is_staff` and the appropriate permissions. You can add the URL by overriding the `get_urls()` method in your `ExampleAdmin` class. Something like this works...

```py
def get_urls(self):
    return [
        path(
            "auto_field/", 
            self.admin_site.admin_view(YourView.as_view()), 
            name='example_select2',),
    ] + super().get_urls()
```

Being able to make these sorts of changes is core to being able to take your Django to the next level. The first option works but go with the second if you can.

Comment: Thanks @D.Morell, but maybe I didn't explain myself well. With the status model I create my category and the relative sub_category. And after, in the example model (using form model) I choose category and after the sub_category related to category choosen.

Comment: Ad example: with Status.models the client can create the category of a product, for istance "car" and the related sub category "whell", "steering wheel" and so on. After, when fill Example.models and choose in category "Car", the client can select only the sub_category stored before ("whell", "steering wheel"). I hope that now my explanation is better